# Finding value in multidimensional array based on value of another key

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

On a PHP page I am working on, I have an array I'm trying to fetch data from that appears like so:

```
Array
(
[races] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [mask] => 1
                [side] => alliance
                [name] => Human
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [mask] => 2
                [side] => horde
                [name] => Orc
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [mask] => 4
                [side] => alliance
                [name] => Dwarf
            )
...
```

I'm trying to get the value for [name] based on the ID. I know it would be easier if the ID were the key for each array, but I'm pulling this array from an API and have no control over that. Any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: Try using a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use foreach loop:

```
foreach($data['races'] as $item)
{
   if($item['id'] == $id) // $id is you id for comparison
   {
     // add your code here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value in a loop like that:

```
foreach($array['races'] as $race) {
    if ($race['id'] == $id) {
        $name = $race['name'];
    }
    // Rest of the method
}
```